# Recognize White Text with Black Shadow on White Background

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ocr, javacv

I'm trying to extract text from images. The text is always white, but the background can vary and also be white, resulting in the following output when only considering pixel color:

[image: First Output]

As you can see, the white background will "eat up" the letter it surrounds, as is particularly the case with the first "G" and the second to last "go".

Now my idea to tackle this problem was to take the black shadow of the text into consideration, which after all also seems to be the reason why the "G" is still readable to us humans. However, I don't know how to go about this, and I also can't find any ressources online.

This is what I've tried so far: Since the shadow is to the lower right, I check if there are black pixels within the three pixels down or to the right. This gives us the following result:

[image: Second Output]

It's already better than the first output, but there are still many false positives, that seem to be quite obvious to the human eye:

Some pixels under the "G" remain white (highlighted in red in the image below) because there are black pixels to their right. The algorithm treats the black pixels as their shadow, even though they are actually the shadow of the "G".

[image: Second Output with Highlighted Pixels]

How can I improve my algorithm so it knows the shadow belongs to the pixels above (the "G") and not to the pixels on the left (the red pixels)?

My first thought about it is that the shadow of the "G" seems more horizontal than vertical, so it's likely it's the shadow of something above and not to the side.

Any thoughts?

P.S.: I'm not asking for a ready-made solution in a specific language, but for a general approach to the problem. As long as I'm directed to the right direction, I'll be able to implement the approach into the language myself. :)

**EDIT**

Here is the original image:

[image: Original Image]

Comment: can you show the original image? Is there a general difference between the shadow of letters and the rest of the background? Human cognition is very good in filling in unrepresented parts of geometries, you'll probably not find any easy solution or maybe even no solution at all. If you know all kind of objects/fonts that could appear, you could try quite simple object detection techniques like chamfer matching to get a "there could be a 'G'" answers. Especially if you already found some other letters and a stroke width.

Comment: I added the original image to the question. I think the shadow of the text is quite similar to some of the object, so it's hard to determine with 100% certainty that a pixel is a shadow.

Unfortunately, I do not know what fonts could appear, a lot of the text is actually Chinese characters (= thousands of possible characters vs. 26 letters per font).

Regarding stroke width: I actually don't know it. I just wrote "3 pixels" as it works well for this image, but maybe not for others.

Comment: I'm just throwing ideas in there: could you use the fact that the shadows are like a copy of the letters, only shifted by a few pixels in a certain direction that is the same across the whole image ? This could let you identify those parts of the letters close to the shadows. From there, you can probably figure out something to get the whole letter.

Comment: for example, if in your first presented image, you already recognize "O go g      o" and are certain that you recognized that right, you can compute the stroke width for that image and the line where other characters will/could occur in that image. But obviously such assumptions only work for "noisy characters", if those assumptions are constant for the given font(s) and language(s) for a single image.

Comment: @Sunreef You mean the reverse of what I'm doing? Identifying white subtitle pixels starting from the shadows rather than identifying all pixels and then reducing them. Sounds like a promising idea, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Micka: How should I know whether parts of the image are recognized correctly? Using OCR and checking for the confidence level of each recognized character, and assume the area around the character has been correctly recognized if the confidence level is above a certain threshold? Or do you have any other ideas?